# jq error, usage message when piping

Tags: bash, jq

I don't even know how to title this.
So if I use `jq` on a json object, it throws an error. If I `cat` that object, then use `jq`, it outputs the json in a nice format. But if I then do ANYTHING to it, be it redirect it, pipe it forward to something else, or even try to grab it in a variable, it spits out the usage text.

```
da@nu:~$ jq dada1.json
jq: error: dada1/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
dada1.json
jq: 1 compile error
da@nu:~$ cat dada1.json|jq
{
  "output": somethingsomething
}
da@nu:~$ cat dada1.json |jq |head
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
....
da@nu:~$ da1=$(cat dada1.json |jq)
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
...
da@nu:~$ cat dada1.json |jq > dada2.txt
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
....
da@nu:~$ cat dada1.json |jq 2> dada2.txt
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
....
da@nu:~$ cat dada1.json |jq |tee -a dada2.txt
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
....
```

I have no idea why this is happening :/
Also the variable I set is empty, and nothing is being redirected into `dada2.txt`

EDIT: Not a fix, or an explanation, but I can avoid this by just doing `jq '.' dada1.json` and I can manipulate the output from there.

Comment: From stackoverflow, but relevant: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not helpful at all, unfortunately.

Comment: you might want to read `jq --help` or the man page: `jq [options...] filter [files...]` -- think about what part of `jq dada1.json` is the filter and what part is the file

Comment: `dada2.txt` is empty because errrors and usage are printed to `stderr` but you only redirect `stdout`.

Comment: @Panki but why does it perfectly print the output when I just `cat` the json and pipe it to `jq`, but the moment I do anything to it, it gives the usage instead?

Comment: You are not specifying a filter, according to the output of `jq --help` stated above.

Comment: Folks are getting hung up on the *first* example (which should be obvious from the `man` page), but everyone seems to be ignoring the rest of the question.  Yes, `jq dada1.json` should fail, but `cat dada1.json | jq` should (and does) work for the OP.  But then all of the rest of those examples (e.g. `cat dada1.json |jq |head`) *should* be working as well.  Why aren't they working for the OP?  Those scenarios work for me with`jq-1.6`.

Comment: @Mesos To glenn-jackman's first comment, can you provide an actual minimal `json` file that you are using that exhibits these problems?  The one referenced in your question is not valid json.  If I surround the `somethingsomething` with double-quotes, all of your other `cat` examples work properly for me.

Comment: I suppose you need to use `filter` with `jq`. And the default filter is `.` .  So `jq . <your json file>` will produce correct output

Comment: @RaviTiwari That's already been covered in the comments, but that only explains the *first* example, not the other others.  See my (partial) answer for more details.

Comment: @Mesos Also, `jq --version`  Please edit any results (of this or the previous command suggestions) into your existing question.

Comment: Seems to work with `jq v1.6`. OP has older version. Try upgrading and give it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, @glenn-jackman's comment is the correct answer *for your first example*, but I was sure that would lead to the question of why it worked when you `cat` it, and ... it did!  Technically, a separate question, but it's honestly a logical part of explaining *why* your original attempt didn't work, IMHO.

And, to be fair, I wrote up most of this answer before realizing that I, like everyone else in the comments, was ignoring the `cat dada1.json | jq | head`, et. al. failings.

So let's start with the answer to the first example:

When you invoke as `jq dada1.json`, the first non-flag argument (not-starting with a `-`) is parsed as the filter, as @glenn-jackman pointed out in the comment.  `jq` thinks your filename is the filter.  This should be evident from the man page synopsis that was mentioned in the comments.

And yes, as you've discovered, the correct invocation in that case is `jq '.' dada1.json`, to have it parse the filter first, then the optional filenames at the end of the command-line.

So what happens when you `cat` it (i.e. pipe it)?  As far as I can tell, it's actually *not* documented in the help/man, but this bit of `jq` code comes into play:

```
 if (!program && (!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) || !isatty(STDIN_FILENO)))
    program = ".";
```

Which, as far as I can tell, assigns the default "program" (i.e. "filter") if:

- There's no existing filter parsed from the argument list
- Either STDIN or STDOUT are a pipe

So it basically does an "intelligent fallback" to allow invocation with just `| jq`.

As for the rest of the examples, where you redirect the *output* and it fails, that works for me (and others in the comments) under `jq` release 1.6 (and later).  Earlier versions had an [issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1028) with redirection (thanks to @fra-san in the comments for nothing this).  We're guessing you are running an older version.

E.g. on 1.6:

```
> cat dada1.json | jq | head
{
  "output": "somethingsomething"
}
```

```
> cat dada1.json |jq > dada2.txt
> cat dada2.txt
{
  "output": "somethingsomething"
}
```

```
> rm dada2.txt
> cat dada1.json |jq |tee -a dada2.txt
{
  "output": "somethingsomething"
}
> cat dada2.txt
{
  "output": "somethingsomething"
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my previous (useless) comment. Here is [the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1028) - `jq` 1.5 doesn't assume the default filter if both stdin and stdout are TTYs; 1.6 does.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you like to edit that into the answer?  I'm happy to if not.

Comment: Please feel free to edit it into your answer, I wouldn't do it right now anyway.

Comment: Yes my version is `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe` on debian, but I can't seem to update it from repo.

Comment: According to the [Download jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) page, *"`jq` is written in C and has no runtime dependencies, so it should be possible to build it for nearly any platform. Prebuilt binaries are available for Linux, OS X and Windows."*  Since 1.5 is the most recent packaged release for Debian, you can always download the 1.6 binary and put it in your path (I recommend something like `~/.local/bin` (or wherever `systemd-path user-binaries` points to).